# Two logicians who each pick a number secretly between 1 and 30

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic, word-problem

Recently a logic question has become quite popular. Here it is:

Two logicians (A and B) each secretly pick a whole number from 1 to 30 inclusive. Each knows the other has done this.

A: "Is your number double mine?"

B: "I don't know. Is your number double mine?"

A: "I don't know. Is your number half mine?"

B: "I don't know. Is your number half mine?"

A: "I don't know."

B: "I know your number."

All the statements are true. What is A's number and how did B know?

My though process is outlined below.

> 1. Assume for the sake of contradiction that A is a number between 16 and 30. Then, A knows that double their number cannot be B, as B is between 1 and 30. However, assuming A is a logical logician, why would they ask such a question they already know the answer to? This implies A's number is between 1 and 15.

> 2. B first replies with "I don't know". Assume for the sake of contradiction that B has an odd number. Then, they would know that their number cannot be double any value of A, and would thus reply with "No". Thus, a contradiction, and B must be an even number. B then asks if A's number is double B. By the previous section, this implies that B's number is between 1 and 15. So, the possible values of B are 2, 4, 6, ..., 14. However, if B's number is 8, 10, ..., 14, then B already know that A cannot be twice B's number, since A is between 1 and 15. Thus, B's number must be 2, 4, or 6.

> 3. Here's my first problem with this logic puzzle. By saying "I don't know", A is implying that their number is 4, 8, or 12; otherwise, A would reply with a definitive "No". Then, A asks if B's number is half of A's. Why would A ask this? The only answer to A's question from B's side is "I don't know"; if B answered "Yes" or "No", that indicate that B knows A's number, which I don't think is possible with just the first 3 statements.

> 4. And here's where I'm just confused. B says "I don't know", as expected. Then B asks if A's number is half of B's number. Wouldn't this be asking if A's number is 1, 2, or 3? Isn't this a contradiction with the previous statement where A implies their number is 4, 8, or 12? So shouldn't A reply with "No"? Instead, A replies once again with "I don't know", which makes no sense to me.

I likely made a silly error somewhere, please correct me if so! Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can assume A's number is less than $15$.  Yes, he knows the answer to the first question, but he may want to know if B knows the answer.  From the second statement we know B's number is even *and A knows this* and from the third we know A's is a multiple of 4.

Comment: You're thinking too much about what's motivating the logicians to ask the questions they ask. The problem has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. To clarify and make sure I understand, would B answer "No" if their number was odd, which would tell A B's number is odd, and thus an answer of "I don't know" implies B's number is even? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @DarkUmbreon227 Think you meant to put this under Ross's answer, but yes, that's the idea.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen yep, sorry about that. I assumed that logicians had a specific reason to ask each question.

Comment: Hi, I have removed the first part of the title: _'Logic Question I'm confused about, with'_. That was a context, and more specifically: a comment on your feelings about the problem and about your own attempt to solve it, but not a description of the logic problem itself. It may well be an introduction at the beginning of your question, but does not seem very useful as a description of the mathematical topic. However, feel free to revert my edit if you feel the removed part should remain in the subject line.

Comment: The only error you are making is to assume the puzzle author created a correct puzzle. The people that guess 4 as an answer is because they force themselves to make the same error as the author by ignoring that A<=15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will call A's number $a$ and B's number $b$.  From the first three statements we know $a$ is a multiple of $4$ and $b$ is even.  From B's second we know $b \le 14$ then from A's third we know $a \le 7$, so $a=4$

Comment: That's incorrect. If you are A and A=16: Do you wonder if B=32 ? NO. Do you wonder "if B is double 16"? NO. If you don't wonder you don't have a question. For any number over 15 you do not have the question. The existence of the question guarantees A<=15. The puzzle author missed this and now people are trying to guess his intentions instead of actually being logical.

Comment: @ThomasAn to be fair, we don't have reason to assume that by asking the question, the person implies that they don't know the answer. I initially assumed that, but the puzzle works if we don't. And it actually makes sense, since they want to get info about the other person's number. 

This would become the more natural assumption if the puzzle was amended to state that the goal of the game was to figure out the other person's number first, because then A would have incentive to ask a question that can give her information without disclosing any to the other person.

Answer (score 0):

This puzzle is malformed at the very beginning. it can only be solved by assuming A can ask a question he doesn't have, because why not.

When A>15, then asking "is B=2*A" means that 'A' is **asking** a question but he is not **having** that question (since he already knows that 2*A > 30)
So, the common arguments made are to decouple the questions "he has" from the questions "he asks" in order for the puzzle to have a solution, by mimicking the same erroneous assumptions as the puzzle author. It's simpler he asks questions whose literal answer, even he, doesn't know. (which can only happen when A =< 15)

A question existing is one thing, while a question being useful is another thing. Even if the question does legitimately exist in his mind when A =< 15, it's still a useless question. It can exist, since the answer to it's literal wording is unknown even by A, but it's useless since B can't answer it with precision. At this point, and only this point, can we apply the reasoning of "Let's ask it anyway even though B can't possibly know the answer, at least he can give us a clue if he has an odd or even"

Comment: To be fair, we don't have reason to assume that by asking the question, the person implies that they don't know the answer. I initially assumed that, but the puzzle works if we don't. And it actually makes sense, since they want to get info about the other person's number. This would become the more natural assumption if the puzzle was amended to state that the goal of the game was to figure out the other person's number first, because then A would have incentive to ask a question that can give her information without disclosing any to the other person.